# Swap selected items between spinners

Tags: android, spinner

I have a problem changing the items from spinner1 to `spinner2`. Ok im creating a translator. I have a `spinner1` with some languages and a second spinner with the same languages. I select a "from" language from `spinner1` and i select a"to" language from `spinner2`. Ok, all I want to do is that when I press the button it swaps the selected items of spinners. I don't know how implement this.
Here my code:

```
public class Example extends Activity {

ImageView MyChangeButton;
Spinner spinner1, spinner2;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

MyChangeButton = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    MyChangeButton.setOnClickListener(MyChangeButtonOnClickListener);

    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter
    = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
    R.array.firstlanguage, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);

    spinner1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner1.setAdapter(adapter);

    spinner2 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
    adapter2.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner2.setAdapter(adapter);

   }
 private ImageView.OnClickListener MyChangeButtonOnClickListener = new ImageView.OnClickListener(){



   public void onClick(View v) {

      ------>//Here the code that i want to do


       }


   };

   };
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

what I understood from your question is, you want to swap values between two spinners.

If both of these spinners are using same source you can do something like below.

```
int spinner1Index = spinner1.getSelectedItemPosition();

spinner1.setSelection(spinner2.getSelectedItemPosition());
spinner2.setSelection(spinner1Index );
```

Let me know if this work for you, or else we will find another solution.